# Two different login pages with keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I have general users which access our applications those use single sign on (oidc).
But for support user we have an internal idp we use and for those i want to have a separte login page (could be different subfolder or what).

That means normal user access https://personal.page.io and support user would access https://personal.page.io/support and get the adapted login page

tried multiple idps and different realms

Comment: What is the exact keycloak-related question here?

Comment: how can i define based on the url which ipd i use to login?

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by using Keycloak's "Client-suggested Identity Provider" feature.
To put it very briefly, you can pass a url parameter called "kc_idp_hint" in which you specify which idp to use.

For example:

```
GET /myapplication.com?kc_idp_hint=facebook
```

Or with the keycloak.js adapter:

```
keycloak.createLoginUrl({
        idpHint: 'facebook'
});
```

You can find the full documentation here: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_client_suggested_idp